# Meaning of 'not A or B'

Tags: sentence-meaning

I got this sentence while reading a book:

> The steps we refer to are not purely computational or, in a wider
> sense, ‘practical’ (although in the book we deal with quite of few of
> these).

I'm confused if the 'not' applies to the computational and the practical at the same time.

Among two interpretations,

1. (not computational) or (practical)
2. (not computational) or (not practical)

What is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short version of "not A or B" is:

- not A and not B.

So it is neither!